# Can you send images in data:uri format to GMail?

Tags: email, gmail, data-uri

I'm making a web app in Django that sends user an image to their email.

The way that seems most attractive to me for sending the image is in the [data:uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) format.

However, I tested sending this email with a data:uri image in it to my GMail account, and the email shows, but without the image!

I know that Chrome and Firefox can both open data:uri images. So it's not a browser problem. But I don't see the data:uri image in GMail at all.

Does GMail not support data:uri images? Or possibly I'm sending them wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not supported.

Mail clients simply remove this from your post.

Here is a good reference of what can be supported:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I don't see where this table talks about `data:uri`

Comment: It's not supported. Trust me.

Comment: What way would you recommend for sending images? Multipart, attached or external link? Or something else?

Comment: What's the problem with multipart?

Comment: Nothings wrong - it's just an attachment and it will behave as such. If you're tying to embed an image in the email body itself, only externally-referenced images will work.

Comment: Multipart messages work fine in gmail. Any that are unreferenced within the code will just appear as attachments, you need to make sure they have `Content-Disposition: inline;` set though.

Comment: Can I at least know WHY GMail decided it wouldn't be supported? It's *such* a useful feature! Anything that will bypass the stupid "Images from this e-mail were hidden" thing which really is only helpful to prevent loading of external images. WHY doesn't data:uri or multipart just work? WHY!?? WHYYYY!??!?1/1/1/1

Comment: What's really weird about this not being supported; The MIME encoding system that allows emails to have attachments is almost the same thing as the base64 encoded data URI scheme. Except the base64 encoded data is appended to the end of the email body, and referenced with an identifier (IIRC).

Comment: I wouldn't say Mail clients don't support it, but rather mail clients might not support it. I tested sending an image in HTML email via data uri to GMail. GMail just rendered it as plain text. But it rendered fine in OS X Mail app connected to GMail account. So the message is ok in GMail, just that GMail won't render it in its UI.

Comment: @n2liquid-GuilhermeVieira http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55061/can-malware-be-attached-to-an-image

Answer (score 21):

Not supported. It's also blocked in other clients like Outlook.

Some reasons:

- help avoid viewing potentially offensive material
- with low-bandwidth connections, blocking inline images allows the client to decide whether a particular image warrants the time and bandwidth required to download it

You can attach an image with the src attribute pointing to a separate part of the message using a Content ID (CID).

```
<img src="cid:imagecid"/>
```

```
--001a1141059012513a055a1b9499
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <imagecid>

R0lGODlhDwAPAKIEAP/ql9yuA...
--001a1141059012513a055a1b9499--
```

Comment: What an underrated answer. Since very little has changed in the approach of email templates in these 5 years, this approach is just gold.