# Send a base64 image in HTML email

Tags: email, base64, html-email, data-uri

Using a rich-text editor, our users can drag and drop a saved image from their desktop to the editor. The image appears and displays properly in the web page after they submit.

Since the image is not uploaded anywhere, the editor saves the image as a base64-encoded image.

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAFKCAIAAADKUQaBAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhepP1p32zb
```

etc.

But it doesn't show up - not on the iPhone, nor two different versions of Outlook. The image is simply broken. We want to stick with base64 due to it already working with the web page and the ability to view an image if the user is offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to successfully embed images in HTML for display in webmail clients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049453/how-to-successfully-embed-images-in-html-for-display-in-webmail-clients)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Support, unfortunately, is brutal at best. Here's a post on the topic:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/

And the post content:
[image]

Comment: Marked as answer because it simply is the answer: support sucks for base64 and you should try to avoid it when you can. We managed to get them to work, there was actually a bug in the case of this question. However, we had to mandate that Outlook 2007 be used. Apple works just fine with base64 images.

Comment: Supported in Outlook 2003 , but not support in Outlook 2007? What are they thinking?

Comment: what is the alternative ?

Comment: Thanks for this, I was just about to write an SO post with my own base64 sample.  I assumed that by checking my resulting email in two browsers (GMail and Outlook), and verifying that my base64 text was uncorrupted, it should be working fine..

Comment: @AkhilJain this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/36870709/5536005

Comment: This approach does actually work in Thunderbird version 52.6, but it doesn't work in Gmail, Hotmail or Yahoo.

Answer (score 72):

An alternative approach may be to embed images in the email using the `cid` method. (Basically including the image as an attachment, and then embedding it). In my experience, this approach seems to be well supported these days.

[image]

Here's a little more reading: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

Comment: indeed it works, but sadly a few email services will bill you for sending attachments.

Comment: Also, many clients, including the Gmail web interface, will append a copy of all attached images at the end of the message, which is very, very ugly.

Comment: This method works well, there are code examples using it with AWS SES in both java and python in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587432/add-embedded-image-in-emails-in-aws-ses-service).

Comment: Linked page no longer exists so is that code exactly how I need to structure my email's source? More explanation, please!