# embedding base64 images in email body

Tags: php, html, email, mime-types, email-attachments

I'm trying to embed base64 images with png icons in email body, but either I get empty images or I get raw code instead of html. I played around with different content-types based on other posts in Stackoverflow I think it should be first multipart/alternative and then multipart/mixed, however I'm not sure what part should go into email's header and what goes to email body. I couldn't get any good tutorial on that. Perhaps somebody knows some tool that converts regular html document into one with embeded images?

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary='boundary1'" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: StudentOpen <web@mymail.com>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: web@mymail.com" . "\r\n";

    $subject = $GLOBALS['tpl']['win_mail_subject'];

    $emailText = '';

    $emailText .= "Content-type:multipart/mixed; boundary='boundary1'" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-type:multipart/alternative; boundary='boundary2'" . "\r\n";

    $emailText .= '--boundry1' . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "--boundry2" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . "\r\n";

    $emailText .= "<html>";
    $emailText .= "<head>";
    $emailText .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
    $emailText .= "</head>";
    $emailText .= "<body>";

    $emailText .= $GLOBALS['tpl']['howdy'].' '.$tmp_member_username.',';
    $emailText .= '<br/>';
    $emailText .= $GLOBALS['tpl']['win_mail_description1'];        

    $emailText .= '<img src="cid:facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/>';

    $emailText .= '</body>';
    $emailText .= '</html>';

    // facebook.png

    $emailText .= "--boundry2" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-Type: image/png;" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "name='facebook.png'" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-ID: <facebook.png>" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "Content-Disposition: inline;" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "filename='facebook.png'" . "\r\n";

    $emailText .= "iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...AAElFTkSuQmCC" . "\r\n"; // base64 string

    $emailText .= "--boundry2" . "\r\n";
    $emailText .= "--boundry1" . "\r\n";

    $body = $emailText;

    mail($user_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

What do I do wrong? The message I get as an email is messed up. Starts with --boundry1 and then I get raw text.

Comment: You are putting headers in the body. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't attempt to create a valid MIME email message yourself. While it is possible to do so, it's way easier using a dedicated library which has all the edge cases and pitfalls correctly implemented, and all you need to do is call a couple of methods to send an email. This is also easier to maintain if there is something to change.

The two libraries mentioned in this case are [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Use either one of them, with code like this:

(adapted from the Swiftmailer example code)

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

// Give the message a subject
$message->setSubject($GLOBALS['tpl']['win_mail_subject']);

// Set the From address with an associative array
$message->setFrom(array('web@mymail.com' => 'StudentOpen'));

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
$message->setTo(array($user_email));

$emailText = '<html>...omitted here ... 
    <img src="' . $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('facebook.png')) . '" alt="Facebook" />
</html>';

// Give it a body
$message->setBody($emailText, 'text/html');
```

After that, you send it. Done.