# html email not showing as in browser

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

I am trying to create an html email, it shows fine in the browser (uses base64 images as well) but in outlook, it changes the layout as it completely omits certain blocks of text and the images display as grey? And then in gmail it shows as basic un-styled html?

Browser:

[image: browser]

Outlook:

[image: outlook]

Gmail:

[image: gmail]

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/vsdg6212/`

Comment: CSS support in email clients is extremely varied, so it's best to use inline styles. This question answers why you are not seeing images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most email clients filter out/remove certain css tags. If you want to generate a html email that is well supported in most email clients, please take a look at this grid showing which css tags are supported in which browser (for cross client compatibility):

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put everything in a table and should use embedded css. If you're using external css, this may not work on outlook or some other e-mail clients