# how to create bar code like in a horizontal line using css (For Email)

Tags: css

I want to create horizontal line as shown in below image using css.   but unable to create so, i have never seen such line before using css. 
Can anyone who are export in css can help me with this?

[image]

I know basic   [`like this`](http://jsfiddle.net/djdmgefk/)

**Update**
Note: Actually, i have to put this in my email template, so i am avoiding images. Just pure css

Comment: |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only CSS I can think of, is a stretched ([transformed](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform)) dotted border:

```css
div {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    transform: scale(1,10);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I like it. Would be hard to get much variation I think, and may render differently in different browsers...but still, good option.

Comment: Thansk, So "run code snippet" is new feature included in Stack-overflow. previously while answering i used to create fiddle, now u directly created here

Comment: I'm not sure `transform` is supported by email clients.

Comment: Nice approach @LcSalazar

Answer (score 1):

If it's for an email <sup>(see comments section)</sup>:

use `<img src="bars_300x10.png" style="display:block; width:300px; height:10px;">`
 with an image exactly cut as the expected email design.

---

**Using simply a 3x1 px background base64 .gif**:

```css
hr{
  border:0;
  background: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAwABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAADAAEAAAICRFIAOw==');
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: but you are using image .. i am looking for pure css

Comment: @Sundara it's a base64 string :) no external images are used. Technically it's pure css.

Comment: because in email, sometime image does not appear directly, so i am looking for css. Does this work? I will put in my code & let u know tomorrow

Comment: @Sundara Don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email I did not know you needed it inside an email ...:\

Comment: @Sundara I'm not either sure that the accepted answer using `transform` is supported by email clients.

Comment: So my best bet is creating a simple .png image, cut it exactly the size it's needed for that email cell element and go with it. (Gmail now shows images by default.)

Comment: i will try all the code here, & check, when i find it working then i wil re-accept it as best answer. Or else i will look for some other answers.  Yes i will try that also which you just now suggested, lets c

Comment: @Sundara please don't forget to come back and share any useful info :) Also don't miss: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: campaignmonitor.com is your website?

Comment: @Sundara no, but on that link you can find lots of nice info of what's supported by Email clients. A genially useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

One posibility that gives you absolute control about the results is a gradient

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0px, black 5px, white 5px, white 30px); 
    background-size: 30px 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7y934ht/)

You can adjust the size of the pattern, the width of the black strip, the color ...

Answer (score -1):

I commented but, seems like it would work to use vertical pipes (`|`) and then to control their size/color/spacing using css font techniques.  I'll post some examples.  It's not clear to me if using *pure* css is a requirement for you or not.

```css
span {display:block;}
.a { color:blue; font-size:2em; letter-spacing:.2em; }
.b { color:red; font-size:1em; letter-spacing:2px; }
.c { color:green; font-size:8px; letter-spacing:1px; }
```

```html
<span class="a">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</span>
<span class="b">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</span>
<span class="c">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</span>
```

Another option, if you don't need much variance in the appearance would be to create a single bar "image", then set it as the `background-image` of a `<div/>`, and finally apply `repeat-x` on it.

Comment: not the DV but, Fonts are not rendered exactly the same way across platforms so your solution is pretty undesirable, and you cannot control the width.

Comment: For the exact same reason I'm seeing Itay's answer getting downz.