# Embedding an HTML Image in a mail?

Tags: html, html-email

I have a requirement where i have to embed an image in a mail and when the user would click over the image it would redirect him to the new site. I seriously have no idea as to what should i provide in the image src. Is it possible only through html. Require guidance. Thanks.

This is my trial HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title>trial</title>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<center>
<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="siteAddr">
<img style="float:left;" src="myImage.jpg" width="900" height="356" alt="my image" border="0" /></a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email

Comment: Is putting the image on the web an option and link to the URL? You really ought to put alternate text on that image; some email clients will strip attachments and/or block images. In these cases, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***INLINE EMBEDDING (Base64 Encoding)***
>
> Inline embedding is much more simple, mostly because you don’t have to
>   completely roll your own emails and dig around in MIME to use it.
>
> Embedding an image in an email first requires that you have a version
>   of said image as a base64 encoded string. There are lots of web based
>   tools to do this, such as ImageToBase64Converter by Web Coder Tools.
>
> Once your image is encoded, jump into your template, or whatever HTML
>   you’re sending out, and embed it using a standard HTML image tag:
>
> ```
> <img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAESAAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X...more encoding" />
> ```
>
> Then you’re done! Send away.
>
> ***Pros***
>
> Much simpler to achieve Much faster to do Requires much less deep dive
>   into MIME and application code
>
> ***Cons***
>
> Can really increase size of emails especially if you use more than one
>   image Most likely blocked by default in many webmail services Blocked
>   completely in Outlook

REFERENCES: ["Sendgrid Blog - Embedding Images"](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/)

---

***EXTERNAL REFERENCE LINK***

link the image from another site.

```
<img src="http://this-is-a-url.com/this-is-an-image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Please cite your sources within your answer and include the appropriate quote formatting - posting a comment on the question with a link is not enough. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: reference has been added, feel free to edit it to fit the appropriate "formatting" as I can't be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the img src with an absolute url and you're done - if the reader is connected to the internet when reading, otherwise your pic will not be loaded.