# Why I can't insert a base64 encoded image into an e-mail HTML Velocity template?

Tags: java, email, smtp, base64, velocity

I am absolutly new in **Velocity*. Into a Java application I am using **Velocity** to define the template of an e-mail sended by the application.

So I have the following HTML **Velocity template**:

```
<p>Ciao,
    <br />
    in allegato il report dei dati mutui BEI inviati in data ${DATA}.
    <br/><br/>

    <img alt="info" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJzsvXu0b9lV1/mZa629f7/fOee+q5JKJakkFARIAiQEBOSRINja3UMRVGzf7XB0O2yVHihIq2CMojYDFbG1u1G7EZTR2rZ2RBkiKCRIIDwCSQzhkQchlaqk3vfe8/jtvdaac/Yfc/9+twqJ1LlVSbBHzTFq3Fvnnnvub+8111zf+Z3fORc8a8/as/asPWvP2rP2rD1rz9qz9qw9a8/as/asPWvP2rP2rD1rz9qz9qw9a8/as/b/T5OP9wd4pu113/7Tl4/W5ZUpja8sict5NbzSXC+XYSQbr8mrgZyElBIAJSfUHNX+ptYVul/PyNtm7ddVeVuHt331l7/k+sf5sT5q9p+9A3zd//bTL16X/tuGTXllSevXpEFeDIlhXIEbOWdSSpRSyFlwF0SEYYivC07riojQWgNAcGrriGR6r6Dy/tqnN0nVtyWRN3z17/7U9388n/mZtP8sHeCr/+5PvOZiki83ky8r6/LiXAZSLiCJnGKByzAiIghOzjm+lhMiQsoFNyWl+H4k0Voj50zvHdxo6pgZqoq7YxpfNwfr/f1tO/8LsDd8wx961Rs/3u/j6dh/Ng7w+7/1Z+65O13/k2k9/kFzLo+rNUkgDytEhFwGIHZvWhXWpbBZZ8ahcDCOrDcjw5DJJbEWkAzWDcmJ2kDNIMFcndPjU2rvnE5KqwoJ6txJGXrtmINro3XFe71uzb5jbtPf/KY/+nnv//i+pfPbr3kH+P3f/Pbfci0/9icZymuHcY1LZhhisVerFV1hfVgYyBwdrDnYJC5ePKJIYhwKQ04wAAokKDl+rqlScsbV4v8F3B1HUHNKzjQ1tDrXj884OZmYmnF8ugVARFBVVBXrFXenq72RafrWv/o/fM4bPg6v6rbs16wD/IG/+R9+32H/8F8aVgcvHoYRl4xIZhwLnoQhZTbrFQdj4sq1C1zYbGiqrMYMnhhWA26NnDKZBAXEDBcnLcdBThEF3J00ZHoDEphCd0U0nEFE6GqYGTeniZMbE8d1ZrttaHNSAu2NWiu9d4rw/tam1/+NP/b5/+Dj/R5/Nfs15wD/5Te+43OfNzzyf23G9OKUC6QI8ZIym/XAOI7kJFy5dIELFwbWmzWDZNSUUgrizjAMJAE3ZRwGzJQ05vjVoQwZc+J73HBS/FmKiGACIgk6NAFXRZuScqHWioswbSvH25kbN05pXdlOM70bYPRuuDXc9f1N/Q/9nT/xeW/8eL/Xj2S/ZhzgNX/tgTteZB/8v1N79IvLuCaXNavVCnenlMJqzKxXIxcOVly5fAkSrDYDgjNIRpLgOOLCUDIpF4rEri1DYhgS3g0kFh4gp4SaxWITOMAF0IRlMIM6KzlFJFBX8LQHhtUN78L16ze5fvOEbol5nqmtY2aRYbQZt/7GYz34Q9/x1a96/8ftBX8E+zXhAL/5r7z9a+60B79ZUFJZk3JhHFcM44qDg0Imc7AZuXrpKCLAKMtCD/F7EZJ1chIysscIuJEEVquMZGcYhSJOybsFj/BuFjhgOy9/TQXVRO8tUL+DpIyLs53b8j1Ow0kpYQ1q7Tx2/SYnp2fMVZnmSrc4Gnqr4I3a9PXf/nVf/Bc+1u/3P2UfVwd49eseuOMTxl/63rE9/GrJA+PqAJdMygOHmxWrceBgM3Lt8gXG9UgSSCRShiEJMgirYUCKoFPs1IPDkYN1JmUll8xmZWSPRY7jIZNyLH4yyDnRWiePGbUAga0pqsK2AZaZttBapUOc981jcc2Zu5JItN5wDQd59PEbTN2Y5xlT2E4zuFHnLV7nt7VLd/+3/+hPvOLtH893v7OPmwN84f/8ni97gT7wBpseo4wHkcenwtHhIcMmkzTxnDsuc3Q4khHSUMhJ4jhYxYIOklFxLqxWrC8OrAsItg/x4+DxkFkYsqBV93xAX9B/yYnWlZwjPUhC/H/JdANrxqyB+qcZ2py4eboNJlGg905dIkidgzdIJG4cn/LIYzdxhLlFRIiMYabNW1Q2X/1df/YL/ubH/s0/2T4ODuDymm+6/y/defzTfy4nIQ8rXDKbzQFDjnw+58zz777G0VhgLBSDcVXIrniOj1yGwtGFAzZrYUhOSpmF0wEzUk5kgdUQTF8qieyCEgSQaIRv9yB8UkpYioVukyJZEBNm4ueogXbFEUQSj58YZzcnhOXv58TcPDIBg96M3jsPHZ8wzzNdjfm0Mc8T5tCnE8z4B/e98NVf9eY/fMfxx34dwj62DvA6T1968Avfe+mxn/+NgpMPNuQSyH41BnO3Xq+5844LHByuKWoMq4Hk4EnJaWC1zqwP1qwPCpuSQEGyMeQUZzUB6nICdwVgEJAc0QBjoYGhd9s7gWfZ794d6Jsr4VECOBjhBEhEi6owT3ByekY7m/Eh46q4Z6ZtRXHq3Hnw5jHbs4Y2xU3Zzg3rM9ob2vVt16+8+jX/+quu3fyYrsViHzMHeM23+3p4+BfedfToO15CGkllpAwjq3FgHFcgicsXDrh69YgxF9brQsLICCawWg+sNhsOD1eURCy4KWXMiBqp8CQnSDnhBjkvT2mAG0MxhhJpoOoSDRZSRywA5WwJMMxukUMpJ7RHqtjUcE101WAFS+b4xszpySlaPbDKUJhrw1pnFuHRR0559PoxjoIa21lRrbR5S6/b6zfv+LQv+rd/8t7/8LFaj519TBzgZa/z8QUX3/e+1Yfe+vw0rDEKR0cHDCWTy0jOmSsXD7l85YgxJVZDIG4TKJ44PNqwuXiBVQZEGdaxA1cJel2cgIgCELm94PvzXjUiQUqB5nFjWJi/nmLXigiQcFdKybQeeKDrcjxY8AW6/GpLQJnVSJLoZtgMN48nzm6eRCFqldHuNHVqNR7fbnn0oRtAAMhaO9vtGT432nx2fXruZ73me7/2Be/4WKzJztJH/V/4Nh+uXLrvnbz3Lc93yRiFYYz83RHM4PBow9GFNaNATkIXY+odUWF95Yj10QEisdvKKqMVaMZskFLsZictyNzIKRbIPc5/LCM5Y54jlBtM3elkTME9Fl9VMQNVMLPADilAojn7xe+qoNAMkiTUQTSRS+LwcMXRHRfxnJm2RrNwvjwKV44OuXjhKDBAN0ScUhJahFRWl9eP/eSbXvOtH37FR31NnmAfXQd4nafPfuz+Hzu478c/KW9WeFpRSmEcR9QFyFy6fMiVi4eUvJAvDmdnlfVqZH3nEetxHTy9RPrWZsNMcRJJoaXYqTvkv0vRTDPdM0amC7Qlx28V1MNBuhpdDfVEUzAyrQnTZGhP9CY0BUfIKSE5MMfO6QzQqtDDOWoNfODjwIW7rsTR4oIu0UiSc+XyhisXD/cRRySzGldoySjj5UsPvvXff8HfevRlH9V1eYJ9FB3A5TOvnf2bo/t/6FVuSvfCMK4YVyMiOXb+hQ3XLh+SUhRjpjNjOzU2R4ccXLsY0cA6rk6fK1NT1BNIRnc7VGGalK0GkTOnzGmHGfYkTp2Vrko3qF2xHmSP9WADAayDttjhnhNdwEj0BnWCG7NxOhu2HDuagL4cKQXc4nM1N5JCnzoXr12krEZqNebacHeGlDk6Gjk4WuPJQaJUvVqtkDyg6pcP3//GN3/2355f+tFbm1v2UXOAV/wt+4aj93zflyaBbonxcARATTCHq5cvcO1os4RCoc1Kt87h5UMOLh4BsXieohwrKYMRwEvjhZtl5grWMzYF7UsHrxF2+6TUre5/Vp1jh3YBzwn1xDzb3lF0oYZ71YgqBWaMXsCbo9WZtoH++2S4R3rY6+LAqqg5nR7gdUysLmxYH6zj757W+IxSuOvqZY5WkfkYt9RJJgXwyxfu/7f/5NXf5gcfrfXZ2UfFAT7lr/p/cfGxn3i912O6Fw4Oj0gWRI+7sx4zV+64QBnCKWrtqCpHly9iZUTVmU57pGiynPHidDcwmGpj1s5UG6odS3FGi6eo8acAiToIOuaoAS/If2d90QBIuYUdvMf/m8JWYdY445OkWz/TDDQvwE6Z544t35uJbAJN9AJzDdp42GxYXzyiW2eae4T/ZNxxx0UuHq2xbOTNSC4DB5s1aTjAT09fefHRd33PR2N9nmj5mf6Bz3ud33Hn+EtvSb/wliGtNqwPjhAhCByH9SZz953XgmgpidobWo3Da5fJw4CIxJm7ACVvTt5kHF3y6GDbWIpESQCXOFY8iBzMsO6478q9CRNDcqZ54Icu4CI0M5Q4p1Xg6kZ4+XMSr3oufNIVuOcCHI1ws0GtCcxRDDWndQMR5jbDoiAiZ1SVqiEcsclpDqkUKIWTm8dL+im4CiUJJyeVNs1YFjBfUlTDb3zwxc//ym85vO/7vuX7n+l12tkz6wCv83TP+vjHN+/9vrvTGHn+kBNeEikXVjlx7fIl1qsRUaeaYl3YXLlAOVwFN58kdmYuDCmRN4nWKtagi5FEyJJwX9Izj8IM4pgFpWvdcEAckmTMFfGMqZHIuIEvHL64YD2OmVfckXjFncJyWgFQElxawfMO4aTBSXfMgihKKdF7xyyyBh2E7obv4mpddARuqIGZk8fC9ngbju6CpMSwSWy3irrRWoDclDNNQW586POf83u+64cf+N6/+IvP6Fot9oweAS89sm84fPiHX2bayWVgGIZI3YaRcUysN4ds1qtIsZIznVWGzQYfBGmLGkc1tHfaaa0x3ay0U8WzkyzRE/RFm9ctdHokqD34+LkGAyc5ELh5CDwgHMUjeCzKnzjDkcw9h8JLLn9kWmQzwEvvhGsX0pI91Kjy5RSOOCb61Kl1+bxzOEl3WwpMLaLTemS8fMS2zXTpMMBBWXPhcMUgGTPDCHIqh2CB8f4f/n8+7X/1K8/kWu3sGXOAl/xlf+5Q7/8z+uiHKOM6RJkpk8oYqZMVrlzeBLJXY3s6UzYHpKOR3Ae21tDsqMveEZrpXrzZzyxUPSJYSYEHPH5V11tgSoLarXNHXTECH9TWghZM7HkDtXCk5MbLn/urv4qra7i6gdUY/5aRaHND8WAMSziQuzPNldr6Xmgq6Rb7KAyQ15ze2NJao0vn0oVDzCHnzLCKQlTKBQC78cDlzfahb3um1uqJ9ow5QD7ku/j5H1pJCjGGqgaLtjBuly8fkkjMtXE8zVguDKtNlElz38uye4pFaS1El7VHUaX3Tj8zaq0A9ATNFO3BsiHxfa3rvqzr6rQWhSIkqOMgiCLMhuq385I7E+Upvok7N7AaMto0wv8Y/IVaYACfhUqg/aaN1tp+4WutoStYC8OlDZTC8Y0Zr/F5L15YhZhFooIJMAyFlAv5fT/6O1/+Lf75z9R67ewZcYC7vn7+itWHfupLik8R9s1AQouPJA42a8ZxDEHFwq6tLl5CxWmnjp3F9ztCPe60Ou93s5RA3DlneupIy8zHjdTiOGjZsWa05kHqECCqdQWJpo/aGm5CrXHGthZO0w1ac55/+NSf9eoaMPBVpgPehem4Mx83+hzObi3SQkmZ2sIpezJYRX2g945vnfXFy7g4p1NDVdmsNozjKuTqWSCPmBnjONKOj1mfvftf8Toff7XPeB57BhzA0+FF/RbufwepjHQDX8dDlJzwMXOwCnR/WltQvJsLQQM7yEZIG0I8YYasPXbTgqJ773Q3qhlehSZxlupS63cEOyj0QhR2PI6Yvmj7d5FINRwiKN1wEiSRc+bS+qk/bUnhXO3M0R78Batlwc2p2ulq1NZDGuahCvJZaa3ty8++FlhDXl9gW2fqUpK+cDRE5KTgxeOocSibgr3vJy+/9FL9n57+mt2yp+0Az/vz7Q+Xh3/qnrSrs+cBKpSx0A3GVBg3YwC6qTOU1f6cdnfqWd9HAT2JF9RmRTVj2m9hguXltjOlqcMM7TTCeO/LS0+x8AAsyBxJew6h9kWUYUEa9WZP4gaeqs3V9zIyM8MqSHGm2kMvsJz3uyKSmoeDn4UC2c6WzzwZeTOQhjXH2+1elzAOcfaPu01EpgwjCWN8+Gdff+2b/MLTXbedPW0HWB22r7NfeueSkgW3nUajVcXJXD7Y4KbMqlgzfB0OoAvqN4daK7qQ63Zm5EGwZSdh8au1eLkqglucv0hCt76c74Y1mF2ZiLO51QitpotAoxnTXCMMe+AJ13buZz5pNTR/veOD02unTZFq1BaklpvucYyq4oOgg+JbRw4yOvuegSwHRwEcW42y+GGsry4NL1aMbkFGyYfexUXZfv3TXbedPS0HeM7r6u8pj/3svTkJkiN0ucd57S4MRZBVpiGcnGwpF47oQ0JXEebnplDBUpydKoI2jbAK9GrMs5PFmc33P39WpVpo7liBbp12qvQatLI3oZ51LCc6oEQE2PUJppRwdXQQTlpggadqj506N44bnoRmynwWv+8W6SmS9j0ErYejal6KQbNQW2c+bagvv9/G79N6zeM3z5jOKnmdyUOGxtKkshBZktG2ZXz03X/6uV/j50AuH9melgMMq+Fr5JfeQRlGzBN5jMKGV8fcODzYAHB6OgEJH6KHb66NNsTi92zo5Kg4c21Mavs00N3xle+dIGryEg6GICWzPQ3WbZdF2AStKr0ZDcUyQfW6sEWZxJiTM0lghO1Z40Pn0OL87EOVqUeBqnbbL+Tus+0W3khYASuR2tXjztyWJtSdYzTHJUMyJG1IOXPaGn3b2axHukSDKj0hnlEXxtUav/+dlOf4n346a7ez23aAu/5i++zSf+5VfT4JYsWdIQ2kMtIQyqYwbjKnJxPbrtgQob/3WCw/c7pV2qzYAH1reA5FTtMAP6pKPzV66ZydxVHQe2c7zQHE+q41y5ibYintjxMRwSaYjxuWgkOwafnPDGkZnwNfvPUD26f0zFWdN//CjcgyTPe7vfVbQDOOrcTknXaiSM1sb4ZDpJToGKkntEa6CjDRg6IeVrTWqXSGMeMt05jpvTOsfVE7CWmaWNkvfRWv83K767ez23YAdfnv/EPvY7VaoQallEDXdKwZh8OG3pQbpzPShHz5kJoMX84+9Tif9zthlAB4BHKvreOS42g4c/JhptdgEHPO4QwWZ2j3BfXPLXYlTl3QvuK0yelnAcZM4sjYLZYJ/MJDM+99pP+qz/yv3nGD01kD1XOrn2BXv2hdg+GsnVQTbBJzU3SJXtUC1PZsSHbMK3NeMIgk8qWImI8fnyEiHF5aoarkdaZriXdNJm8G5IF3X74bft3trt/ObtMBPKWL9bfzgZ9BzfeduVH6BUpiWGWmbYTGJoJOTjsLVS2ny8vOIMNCf3ZgFXm7JYIj6FHDd48FayUQ/Ezk1b3VvWYPQEomDQXxAIpzDRKmdmPbA4i6O+SEikBijyve8PZjHrz5kZ3gR95zylvfexo6gqUgZWb0FCnf7I1K36eyXY12onsnmd33LeewOK6Bn7T9Z3AEzVExnabOwbhCPJhE747TQCKS8MB78Kvbv3J763fLbssBrn59/W35vp+7KsMaJKJQtVta+yGFQ5zMNWjgo8M9F96khVNMsYt67yGyUIvjwIxpsmAAMVoLkKRnt5o0d6HThsTEknN329Ovtmj7PS21gBYLm1ZLaJZg5arXYB8z3Kgzf+dHr/MD7znh+qIhAPjZByb+7g8+xPf83PXoHVjfIniiIqi0Ra6mZ4ujni6klET7WO1xLGAxh6DWGqlsX/oIBLQs8wgOV8ynylmNZpIxF1qN5+0eiuXuiZRHxsff+5orX+eXbnPtAbitM6RX+732wM/vZVi4MWTByNCM9WGg77adkaOBIhkHNDXSJMzAUDJ1WxnWA21WcrLgwJuEqlcLVaEMAq7U7qy2AyWBrTtd014Kpjnvq4Oeo0g0Smj3dr2F7o7NBt3oGSQVUChFsNoZKVTr/MAvnPD9P30j2s02S3hfOAt3Dw1gESwlJjfEwbYgBwk1RY9DNbRXHedCbUp2i+PRA5DSNY64A8GOG7oW6pSwFv0J25tbNtdGhmFAasd6jZb1Fs4pIpQP38f4klf8DuD/uF0HuK0IIBfKF+bTh3GJnb6jXnMSmgjrzcjJzTPakCEdsJ2iYbKf1n1P/VxbaPVy7BpPTi+h33f3PVtnmpha7PpJO1M2mi29+ae6r/hBnPm9x25vKUJqN5hbYAqIlHCXp/feIyw7aPa9kHS36GaGbcEnweeMrdiDvd04GTOLr58amgRK2hNXJoVeDTfFllqFOWBLIakFLazitxRNQDpc42XgxtkZeZ3RusjZpgDCJS0M6Ic/jDi/73YXH24jAgx/6vTVg913p/ctPoyBbnPZn7V5k5lNmZoF8XNxxM3wlmAVlG8uA8NBRpsjkyNrAvmeOYuCm5LCO7WVKL50w7IFmzYM5BFMjdIr6ktbVy447I8bc8g9QOMOWOacYUy4hUNId9wU7/EyNIOugS1IXVRAqvvU05aUM6UUGUpfcEVJtwpRC04w6XhT0hB/VpuSNoKK0886shF6bahHNJgnxVVIZcXJ9joyCVcvrOPML+F8khMs9Q6TM7J94LW8zkdeL/V2HODcEWCU8sXywQ9EVcuUVFZLa1T40iYHWu9zR9Z5X+I0iXO6l9g103GlpYUlqwJbmEXxjdBXIdrsJUaxzLUFuJS0zwza5KHqqUOAQEngFufw6a25Pj4Ik9XY4QV6CgIphBwWREyRJwE65k7agA0dVrb/vZ9F5HACi7Si6Bhdwtu5Re2hR/uZE61llkNy1rNhw8IUHjfSkrJ2A6sJ3eq+U3lbNQBxVZoJBwclIttSsnSEUgbGYSR96AEOTs4+7XYW/7YcoIp9iT3yi0SHVBwBOoYzqMVuq61TpeNpoLeZ1mp01/YGLQX5sxRtajJ6Ntoqwq56/NoGhW0oc30j4BZt21X3qNkczlplasbp1JhqZ06NmjvzPKOqTLXTLLiF3XGgZJoJZ3PHNlGzaFmoGk6mQyDvneIIFsXP6JBKHANVaFvFlvYx11vHhjZHcLap0fJCOvU4rvxU8YNMTca8fcKYmQG8RBrs7qQUFapW56W8nrEWx08MusoBLq/fTz5cv/Z2HeDcR0C5a/zc/M7roe03pzGRtytaUjbDirEkHjubwAs9JYb1gE4t1C22fOimbC6M+/ROcOiFYZP24dsJxxARVprxdaGdzKxXI7XHObif8DU5FEfnWxXCcQhNQu2NtEpI8zhPVSklvk9VkapshsQLrozceyUqrSLwngdnfvHRXZ1AYjCEBZ3clqNkp/vvc+T3WQpuM20M+Zp43jurbhXWBRXoc5BVCaeZY9nw7kw3grmUzUg7UZIkTqfGxaMBa7ZQ7J1uRteogbTrD1JW/AHgr3/UHWD1tdO949nDl7VN1HRISQ4LGbXrwe+e6FvISZGU6aqUFmLJPihSnZQG2tb3un/GEfeGM4ZOfzCK65637wbeZ1aHA7M30gRSCj05Zi1IqBqaPHdnHArNQ+dn2cgmeHLmubIaBlpXXnB55PM+4RKf8bwNVw9/BWnkK+CR087fftOH+cDjlZwzWRyfHS/gi7rXTMkpk8yY04wOHmJWDydLKUBhKwJbp3aIvkODDL01RBJ1CzkX8Il26qT1mjqd4D36F8aSqN33XUVuigwZ5hnk8U/ndZ54vZyjqnEbDuC0V+rxgwxyS3plvmuWFcY8MvUaOxOnZ0d6I5eozA05o0DWCjqiFqE99UU61SpsEr6Nql9eG6uU8d6W/vwa6c+YaKL7nj+r4QS+hN7outmlcLJr7kVS5tX3rPmyV1zh2uGv/uh3HBb++Bfdxde84QOYOvNSRrbJGIeCmTK4MJcGJaFNl+xFYKlnWFuqmpJQn5BBqDWOQi+KnhXMogze0SULCUXzzuY+o8XRucccIo+sSLvjZsj2UY6uX7t2Ag+fZz3hvEeA2yvSY4+QUlpCaaG2yLkFo6yN+TQGJm2OVqQk2LZjHpU57xbOUTK1zgzjGpE4j9mlgieJYSPxgjpBhgwF3+n3UuKsdlRnxkVtnGSZ5oXH2dh6vMiUkSLMrfHaT7jIV7zyKnc8hYV/ot1xVLj32sDPPzRHmriAwO3c9iVpaYF9WFJIIdLRlEtMIU3h3GaGzoJZQK/5pJHJdO9LkatgtTNpw0fBPEHtbDGySrSzF6MtxbOcM6SMPPIQ24O7Xw688VwPxzkdQNVeQNnu9feRk0p0zSSHCmd1i0ihS0KOlWGEZkJZ8m9kwKgMeUWtM6UMAYRSwk3YjJG7kzqjRJp5dtyxAbJmeqqMJUa8ag5ZVjHwhZ8fSvAB7k5ZJa5l4Y//hrt5+fNuv8nGycxtGU5hi/BzqSbmDFRhy7SfYGIajjFNi37xbF7eWcjZpxphX/KIe0fI2AIGNSWG3tGUSKWgyZlnZVgbiqIdPDve/Va62yvUfFsikXM5QMrji/3BB+ldg0HzQNUlhXAhpURXJ+nMYJtAvV0ZSoadzNk69AFNu/w8zlI1I62gaaLMoAWsdsQVdKR4Ys6Nkgrdlzy8BvvXgOaOeOJUK6sSAO2LXnTAf//r7+JgfHq6lzPtnKpSPOTavjSdIHnf8xeVzuhqTt6RntESswLMoSVlsByqIXdyjiO0G6TlyFKP91MBVyN3cHPmqmwurDHbRmTzjKiiFKBhxw/Ac9NrgH953mc7HwZI6dquv94R0gKCKAXVyIMhCjyzKaXODEMstghE+75Ed09WEmtYxJNpJei2Y4NRLdQw3pXSIW2MSTvZAzRKE/Imikg+xGJnS0gxEonu8Kde+zy+9KVPiybf2wOPbOPMNcW70LyFMwyhPE4pYVvDSjhk3ULrleEgU3b1pZaYcscXyVrvjZQiS8hJljlFi0Ioh3N3sX172TzpXmLWmmIa57870cRot1cTOJcDWNJrcvx4NC6gxOoNtEXoMKsGFSrCUEowWKlT2/JQPZB/zhmpQpMpUPtqg/ZOkhxiigG0hqS8A2m2hfcvnNUe5MVZDHd262QT+iBkMpsh8fW/+YV87oueGdncLz46cf/1ypLF4kueHiIQohnVFcmKIPjcSSVhGE0Tx3VmQ8FHicj5ELNSAAAgAElEQVS5zvSzCN29LxrIWqPRdEmJd8KRHhMtwKLEHg2sguluqnnQ2f7o46RXlhfof/pRfkU7lwMM681l2z5GWl3ENdMVSgmpkoiAQu0TIhkfjLKMWcmDY2MBN6QNqDt5R3hsCm3RhWmr+CokPMMw0lpFyoj2ji8/P6UEOeOi8UI90UUpVuim/P3f81JecnX1H332dz008/hsfP4LN+d6QW/4qYdC0FkSA0vU0RgUpabL0aMkS0hfKpa7ukNr5FzY9ko+XQiulROyjlA8RyYVk0zCsXZCk2gyVa807awYIrV12/dbmIfs3rePk1L69ed6sMXOBwK75tILrShJOr7OqBbyDLKGrYW0exgGmjhlScBaFYo5rBWtwliWVqps5L7o//pMGkZS75ASrgpL2RW3kJslQZCotqkjSx+/k5mmzl/7yv948d/3eOPbfvQR3v6uh7n7xRe5+8Lzecnl4Sk/87/4iYeZJGEztGX6Z3ZovgymTIL3wDIItN7J5qRxIKmgy2SKVkDrzKZt6LnTdxmDCJp3SuiFAj5raF90Ei2O1a0vUWPK+NCwJrg2zBPJRtz0tvo8z+UAgh221hiGNT07TIbsRBxbKKXjNmDWKSnwgSyl2t4q2QfKBUG3ggxOSoV56fRJediTJr7v4ImHD9YtdkjzitclNGoL8FgGfsdnPo8vvffi/rNuu/NP3vE43/6D9/H4wzehw0vuvcRdR0/9kd/4s9e5cTpHY2BJKAlVQ5YZRGqhVVRzZCGbrENKwryt4Swi5GEE7RiJ475d9j8ksWiemQRrwEHcY6B9SRsXjkVdovll61iqCLsoI2ir0CsCtyUSPZcD5B6LA0uBxwztLapwpWC1YDKjmklzp6/KPmz70uRhPTGsM2fVSc3oWaEmhoOO5QyzL4zeMopFO54Nm4AUIEsxkhikAXV4wcUNf+yLnrf/nPffbLzuX97HW9/14X0efvXqAZ/1ootsylOfi/UvfuqhWIESzocq4o4vRRs3Z+6V5AnJTpEEGZrG53czuiQG6ZEasiB9j+JZSrF5egVbhVbBt5neG2UYYwilCG6O9RmXpbF10r0KKueMjuwHXZ7XzgcCVU+l22GtlUxGNitkGbGCBv+9q9jt2CpyeHr36KnzE2gXnHpqSBIGL7AB3RqpKzV18lmOfHqMGntrGhc8VCjLhDB1yG4cjYlPeeFlrm7i62+575Sv+4fv5rGbJ4uAIxD3PS++xGfc9dRbgD50febf/YcHQ6vXiJbvJQMSh3nRkkvKqBtOoc6VEahANsdJ5N1VNItgJUkUvOZ5xnYzjVfBG/hpiqOE6JXYVThDJyBRpJiXopIvSiJVchX6I3Z6nrXc2fkiQBEtVpCc0SGTLerYuYTix9QXKjP64co43Bq27BpTujbGfCPq68WVppnkCSuOZyOGemkg4LaofNItajRmAITCR3BahWrw57//Q3zosYkfe9sDQb3u2rIdVkPhE56z5rPufuoA8J/9+IP0MbEaCl5y5O2qNLW4a0BiIGXtTskFnRVLwpwS0izqBU2Zu5ObYIMj26VGsAJpmck7MjtlA5zFaBlXxzIx53AZTC0i9K1hovu2uV3pWBZ1sYjfThJwzgjQ++N+8cpF256S1wWXDck1hitJ3msC8DXiim5nZMyR56dEbxVtC5J2h8NCP52XC53y/t4eiDJo9PJFCE/SGdeJ1hdPcAvJmMBP/8z9XLq04YEP3Iio08HWutwOlnnh8y/yX33yxY/wVL+yveEdHwbpdCvhqFX3oK/3tugC277ruNOjs6lXRAXrMWJW3OjZURXoTloZeuLgQemKRxtckmXamGqMvm+OS6SJOgumup8lBAs+0oaMQLqIan/zuR5wsXNRZOXMHrfxCBfFZ4fZ9mKQnQJHUqbbcp/OOCy0buzY7jFEIZ7AmG5WbIR2snz/wgNUDQGkiMQErqT4kJk15gJrWxpJu4PCydR4332PUpmCFt10hnGFDJkyJj77pVf5nBc+dYz0z3/iwzxwY47av8203knc0vFLKpgqmaWJ1aI8HbhgoC/yr7kpU781bFLGUCX1IRhUGRVSoe77GgwZo5W9oWj1kIFZKId7C8CcJaIfbtEad+EyMvf7z7OW+zU9zzertkeSG2kOXX8+GqGVkEM7DIOg3ch5IC3dOG5GnadlIEOnlEydG1mcVIZl+FKApB3qd/H9vN6MwBC7TFJmasZ6yItjOW1ukMrS7iX4KlHKGEOhgTuuXOL3vvLauV7KP3/7Q1FscSOXMWYJdAVxlJgt5JLp1vcDJmyZOmKiuAZA3A2WmpsySqa3RVo2RViv6pA6g2f6FH2GMeI2RtKStiGIYflZzh4TOFEwSxaOkQa9ca6HXOxcESBjv+gXr0Wla7mIyaLAzVAi1Oec8eY0N1x70JV9uWVjdHQAGwwORmyV9hW1ZrtbOWQ/EAJCEaSz7vv3co55AbuBDjLIk858CjQJpK4Iv+6TLvFJ1546+Hvg+sxb3vt4EC4OjpFyXhZd6Eu3b2/zHtvUbqGBJBZv13a+Q/4umXmeI8ItcrVeDCSKQLV1NDm1xuUSrYUMbnuz01tbBKzhCrsiHIB3x2onHdyBn/Km86zlzs7HA4h/MJURXfT6gzfSuKJvGxzdmm/jbgyEONN6AlHyBdnX9HdjYhJL1lASvXU8J5AolEjKQb166PyTG3jU2HOJ9I9F2JlXGdWKlBg/b0vOfWGV+a2fevVcL+Rv/Jv3xZGTV/u7A5DgLHqb99RsZAOxM60vSqGu+6lb6nE/4a4ZJKUSOoAMYLhGFqRnig5BfuUOtQe3EKXliBRajVIy4lEBRBJSHaUj3pGyIedyW9PGzxcBtvLOvnpOjGgXoekcenUSdhb1btMaWvibEzItYKfO1Fo5W8qjglPnKTBB77dUt0tVTXt4/jzHLruVCi3tXr3tG0R2eTV5GUTZZnyI4+Keuy7yqrufehn4eOp8/88/tA/d5kDZTQLbTQZvJIlhkc1kKYoF+NtfLGlRyIk0ONB7b7sWsMjfuxp6sgO6i87AHRuM6WxpLfeQxO04l7npvvtae6MoUKENd8AJ7zrPWu7sXA4wjqu356O7EW1w1pcwF/mqLIAoa1zXhiS2x6ehCh4XmfQ2RI07QehOSPrE7lrtC7LO0W+I9f1M/x0IUwspt5Gia8h22CEjm3CkIsZXftZdHAxP/RH/yY89wI1tqJdbTLYCoGygyxTpGjC1WxzAbgbQbpH2A6o7dPq+y7kvXc8g1EUy1sfELEt/AYla2A+70JOld7LCPDe0K7ktwtObUwS/ZJh15No1Tu45evQ8a7mzcznAQ9928f11vPNxWW+iLj4FP11Pz/DupC2LyjWcIRFMYd1GGxUrQBJnUzx069EKltMin0qGJt9HhXmu+xEp+K1hURSwspy3thscoWhyWhPUBq5cXPObPvF8FdJvf8t9eIobS5LArE5TpVXHNDFXobVgQ3fX0hkJ7W0/WRwWx81Lu/gcaD7njKUnR7Ja4/ma3nrm2g3Jitdodd8vVE8wGjJHpXBAmE+3yDAAd7/9dvSAcH5ZuMtJ/5G2vgJz3UvDYMlfs+7btXbXpu1aquTU9xO6mQP07SaK7btsWuS3aVX2TZC9a6Q/srsLwEMo2diDPs+79GyZ4t3giz/1Du44fOpFn3/8kw/wS4/H7L+GLkKNZR6QLn38HVwDm1gyLAMFNMu+D2F3NNXaFtFIIq1COtf7IldfolwqYwyRWmYH9Vaxmz2GTFkA296iFK29wRn7aFi1Iub45edCP/3Oc67j3s7vADp9nzz/RctYlJk0QypOJiTXPXdUG2C4K5xVsmeaLI0aT2i83HXv7gY3dYtOnX0Y3EnGU6Ev0cJ8Gbroum8R1+XmjtYCRV9eJ37jp55vruLf+6H74tbPYdw7cUz5ZM+6da+Ecj+Int47VmM6+C4N3C0QkmLYpbd9E4rorTmCOyyTUsInYly9Bz5iDjyhvcUQ20mRlWNUrHZcFGyG3kl33kNK59cC7uxcDiAivhnWb/bDe5DeQMFFWRMPy2zI1NAzReZArNobLg3mBifLTqWT2jIoaikudTomy27QhvUAk+4LInaNyheQxiBKKOzFn/oEpuzT773Ma1/01MP/W973OD/zwE3KKqEShZZdf98enHJrFuDOGYB9fb7Zcn9wV3qd9/hmh1dYtIq7CNFbpXVDe0dSQipwvOCF7bQHxq01bFycZm4xWGJuDC2TKNjB8zl76NI7z7OOT7Rzi+Wu/4NLb7NLn/yg50zaVbhqD05gR+b0XU0gatZ6FuKGJI5PoX4xVVKJLpuduLH3HkMXPRo+5nleHMAgFSQPkRNPiqrRloFM2ubgxz1e2pd9xnPO9Uzf9L3vIw0gFh1OuxJvThI/My1RZ5CloHPLGeqOgnfDehxlKZe9U2bZafl7TCpZbCddZ46qIct8oRhkHN/X2oxUQU/qLWc0jdY1i/H6/cK9/45/ent9gXB73cEuJ+1N+Y570amhZ3NU6jRk0FoV05gBoKctNO6LhMnbrqLTIx2y3WCExLyIJXe9Bjtkj6Rbk7YWNlAG2SNuSxFuSQUjcfelDV/8kstP+WF+7Bev88Pvfjg+b/KFyuZWz0GG5o00xg2hvVVquxUlADqK+LDPYnbtXjvSpve+nxfseRl8sYy6Q1JUVBcJvJ22W5VUWECyISfzckNalJ3dFbt0D9yY/uFtrOHezu0AImLe/DvteZ9ITnEDVl4+aD09iw88CrRF7XsG3qZA6xYXOogXMMVOG7a7t0oEW8Cd9ravMezSqNbaLbGI9v3EL6zQTUI2po0v++y7uPPwqQ/T/MbveS9eAsRhSwQSJQ2x8KoKVrBqkdOnkZQz2nv8m+6IyhLSw0GNhd+wW7OPd9bmJzd9CMslF3NHlHhPrrg17LSSVkabFK2xAey0M/dG0ka65xNpXP1/z7uGT7Tb0kt/wcvu+Dd68eUP9TaRzPDWsG3kLH7SqNsF3EUzPFRIT9jRPtV4WIDlGElLs4Sq4brMBuot0PPSX1et7sFWW9qyd1VQSYmrF0d+28vufMrPcf+NiX//7vtRMRgSWvK+1PpHvvAefvJrv5Cf+3Ov3dfyA+kr5kIqY0SkpSiza5E3DwfeDYnej4Rpt0BivKgl1GtCNGRjPk2gNU6AKUggPdYYGwv0s6DNc3ekdbjysh/gu+Rp3Td4Ww7wxr+A0jffpddejtYZb5XNegQ10ljIDawqYgm6RbQ/PoXW9/QtWkmtIS3Fn7cp5C65YBJ6u12XjWmkULtbOtuke8wAEZbdjE9/4VVe/pynXvX7xu/+OVxz3PHTFXHlk+884Af++OfyDV9yLy+4tObSunC4CZ4BTYgFQPU+7wdjdDGaRwNsrXU/fGI38n0/YaQtgNBtoZMVmWdsDj4jydJP2AMDaY3bT/ocGYSLIkkprtiLPg07G/7M7azfE+32JoSIeFL7Tu56KS4tWpysI1UDwS+q2H0Fp0OyZfTL0g/ou8bbPoW35yEG+2tfLmW0W2lYCoXQbrKISqSEkoJ/F1cGMX7f59z9lJ/heO5899s/jGTdg7Pf9arn86b/8fP5lCc40U8/cJPHt3FNvC47WhdhRqD+vge8bSnc7MbUCUH2aI96Pm54X/BaFaQpZk4KwgG2NeREy/sRS/SpIdWD8VNFz7asC9QL91zv7epbb2f9nmi33TJT33Dn29Pdn/VTwgWmactqmfbFHGd96hJNEB3cOkbDT2to2juLkCLOT9eOn7Vb0WHJk/eDld3pEosAEUqFSKVUQ0fwnItrvuQTnnrh51++40GOa90Ppfw7v+vT+dbf/uTb2k6r8rX/6p3YdqLWFsBsWASpCzGVcqFue1wdWwL0Scr7ETfeE2iPa3McJBdkW2G5+k6EiAjtLI6SXRRIjrsh1SDFwA3dNvLslM0R08Gnfiv/VPSXP9d57bYdQEQ8Pdb/ur3gM8mD0qeZseyUKpHmMXVSimEGAHiH04mlyBsPX5YXsCJQMYv2X5eJmikWf3d5oxyELq9PkXXsFES//7X3cjg+dWHkD/7cw5jDC+7c8Jav+2L+m898/pP+/LQqX/4dP8ZP/ux1rCSkLOKPhfgRkeW+QCevhyepmKsv4/G2HXLBl/ROBLzXpYcikVgyjWmOnU8cnVYVmyMbkJTxroi3yDtSRZ/3mfgj+s23uXRPsqfVNNf+9XP+sbzgcz7oXdienXJQcox7USPthzBbPMwS2vAeQKc5Xi2u3yS6fxAJPLDk06QcCFxv0cBmoZqxHD+vdeWOKyu+4uVPHfwBfNrdR3zzV346b/na1/Ky5z65i+ikKl/2v/8IP/KORwJ/TB3vEmqdZd6Paad6j/O+VWSMXe9FsLbMA0yx+7EofLn2vZPjhlWHeSLNLZ676n6zSEowdaw3vClUo59u2aw2tKuf8r/w/Xfdlgj0l9vTHDUqpo8//Pp89+f+vfnDb+ZCucyQjeo5nKB4nGur4OSlxRg3zibk4oB3wVO0j5grMgz4aUUOx+W8XHbQ8kk1ObZtIdR0pxEzAH/9S1/AJ1w9X/fvV33JJ/6KX3/Hh475yu/4Ud77vhgVV3K0oDebYakPWM7RJ5jiWtodGI2JIYSAxIw0gG0XYWfKcFbxZbI5te8xgbiBR2u71cAK0iUaZLYVx5AK6w2s7/1s6s2DP3d76/Uf29O/MOJNd/yf9vwveJ91Z5q2HI5GMo1dUCN3ZzJS22GCJSuYTyEHC+Y1wKFrJ62DOHJtiCWSBmGEGea+J48gbudcHQz8hk8+3+7/SPbtb/0gX/TXfpB333cc7e6E0+3o4V3NITgNJS3TUUQiOqgDzbHWsN6ws5hBLClkYL4TsWxDZST1DKkW6bIuRJkb1IT1huiSRncDr2xWG7j7Vd/46HffcfyMPDDPyI0hYn5y+EflhV9KnY9ZjU7xTipOcsdrBe/7hkZIiEkcCdsTpEXhw91JXbGth1LIdhnFBCokzwvjF3WAHTi86/Ihr7rr6XUBv/2Bm/zuf/QT/NG//+Mcn8TtHhBYJFlCR99fPmEOfY67CWAZHqWGTj0+o4cqWSwhJQgpP+vQJ0Qh1WgBt9PjfYfQk+bVz0Y0vIO3OfiTXlkNifGTv+DGX/iKF/7Vp/Wwv8ye9rRpAH7oOd/Hb330e6YPvvm/nqczLhxtePTxmTSuYBDEwJORmuNWMUpIozxBsZgkUuOuv3Q0hBNsBJMF1NkyjUudtIow2QFS4uAo8QSi7Vz24eOZ73jrB/m2H3gP739ou+QW4CV+pB0CW0UmiejDrXKspriraNfrr3ExYBBcC9hL4ngwV0ubM/vdjhu2XUgwz1i9tUFMJ6ggLpBm8M7hhTv4xM/4vN/5R36LnN3e0/7K9sw4AOAfmv4gL/ny+04/8A83l69sODosnJzOSF4j3iAPmO5eomAeqhk/q5EOjSWKRDVkVMwZVnHXbzTcxZAJm6KWziAklf08ovPYh49nvvOtH+Sfvf0+fv4DNzk+Vdx837ufStznIyLoKj4vCHLizNrhANLkaAJZdn3yHJ9tqXNIGUFnqGlp6jF87kGR2wSN6Jvsjmkj7bgCq3GZoS5t4b1xuG4cveo3ffcP/+WLb5KnPR76yfaMOQA/8fxHec2Df7YOn/QtdX6Ag/UhrQmzzvx/7Z1rjCTXVcd/5956dPc8dvZhY5vEix3LJPHGSuQkCvkQLEeBYEiIlZjIYClCQSCQDBKSCUJIgfAWSICEQMAHRCRLxALlg784ihMZItvkIQccIzaLF9b2Guz1rHdmZ6ennvfw4dzqrmn37K7XO+totUcqVXV1d1V1n3PP43/OPVdDCiK4bIqLizpUsD/szBl0aRmXCqoNWgVC7qBQyGIdYbMFPrMOnz6DqkWl5eUTmzx69CTvvPbcZuBf/nuVx4+d4ovfeYGjJzc5eWzDYu8kBWrwiZWgty2JeNq6tJ58YM0vkgSaFld7A7tU0bqyzqNVhbgMbQN0NX4loC3UVgCqTbAIqAixqNQmiwAThNClQqgcTiyplmctC1ffsv6Ld73tPpELz/rtRBeoPHcidfzos9/wT/7Rbfv3LaBknFxrCM7mEGrqcFlqajB3FvJIQkhaGDiQBMkzNHGxksaj+cwj5lksvfbmSWcJh27Zx2/e+Q4+eev2WP7/Ngr+a3WTrx17ha898zIvbRQce3mdtec2EJ9MkzIJdr9hiubmaCbeUZ9pSUZY25tKUOctMrE1bqwy1DXWoaOscEFi/gMoMVAnhrmhKKGsDNgBmwjaYBBwzJJqXcfGWA2UBV4q9u1b5Na7fvmuR37/6odEXj/wM0sXWQCAD57ez6knjo1e+uLi0p59NDW8sl6jPkPSBJLMvH8SJA+oJNYwaSDWXm0pAxySm3LSbjp3BFNcFj8X7LyLmPL1b9/P9+3dw7uvX0YVnnzhFACvrI1ZL2peOr4J45iGVoVUTIicB9+9FmQUZySJs2nXZUQfnSc0DS64CU4hYlk8XBJLegzcsqoeDOPXYDBvGQdv0dj6xXWHC0SB0AbXKDSBUJndP7A3sO+d9/zFdx98z2dELq7t7+jiCwDAHaffzwtfeGylfIp8tERRetZPV6ZCkwQ3zAltbV2ysgireiBx0fnLo0aIgiCOyXKJnSA4G22uUht1DbhlT7KUUVdiVUjj7QPGfA9BkoDiMOiyhSzWDorgRs5S1DFLSWFxfQgB6igolSWG8NN4nmZyCaONxhhc11CraYMyELbU/IG2QWoTFpUaHYOEAHWBamDPQsPiwR96/Pijd/+4iKztCp+4KGHgHPrq8uNc9/FfWx8v0NQlwzywZzmDJo6IsjJ731YTuDiiohYBlDWMK6SJdXQRI3eisUx8qmpD7pEBSBJgo6E6vomePA2rW7C1fQWQoGKqX7wxMgGy1EzRUHCLiaF33dqD8diqj1toKygMyhOJoV5jnn+H6eu4QceWuWSrRprWRnkZJr+R0EAF2laEtkQKxYUWmgrVwPICjJave/rzf373TwEXNOXrfOniLh/fp2N/+ATvuuG2+vlHbx4MPVlqix+WraJdpwMRIKBVjWSpOURe42gPtqiCip2rGiTEqeJEbN0JDuuUZaBJg604G230QCbawtqUKbZKRBymsQJIQxzZoUXHCkVp3v24hYA1IwhMBUODjWwNdr1WTUAwFe6ahrCxZWsAo5PaB0v71lHt2/O6xqBjbazQc2XZkQ+y9bt+4Zfuvu+jw2dELqzc+3xpd0zAhNTx3sceG73wD+9b3rMEklOUyloRosMXUHW2eoe4qTnIiHMIov3PweULlokDQro97BMXJ6Z0Kn+YbNMSAKTOohCNJd7ikcwZFOvj/dvazjsrWunIJTqN37HUNhhyp200AaVV9+hWQGpr4zIBv7as5MtJSxgXOJcQWivxonXQNEhbsLTgGA2T9Y98+ufv/Jtfvf7bInJ+y5m9DtodEzAhCbSDD4yv/fjh9VOrhGZMlgrLA0Ab83hj+bgGG6ki4FTMi3ZqWy3o1iZhqyT4enuGUVycmi7mNwxiV43WKnFd7mE47W2sLkPyFPx2/8AEITXHrqjMsYubNmrPBBNbH4p6qhFiq1wtqklKu2O+K8TQvFARNrcAb/5P4ibMpylYXoBB1qx/+N5Pf+RSMR92XQNEevuDmeTpkcGLXzq4vGcZlREtwtrYumqQWW0f4pCB9eQJbYtbTmPpeACX4VIlOMGNhtZxI/YemvyY2FdPw5QxpLbahhBn1LosAkuJfT+EaR2CC9G2R4GKJVv9il0RLLTTMKnmlc2A1LX5GE2sfRRnPkiLQb1dNpTWzFUbkFaRtmZlSUmTZv1Dn/jUT37+c4e+camYD5dKAAAO/t2AlZV/H61++ebFpRWQDMkT1sctlSrqBG0Ta58iDk0SXOYNI8CYq94KKNRhDlwysBFvH5gUaUzKqxMgdZPIb3K++/Fx9m1XmezEVL0IiOqkWicEtdg/Mh4NJlCbhaGZna8ZDCMwLQLSWggozhPG0RxoY0hfE8hCy8oeD/V4/cOf/JmP/v3vvuubl5L5cCkFAIDPOt7xgw8NXvnmnctLQ5zPIEvYLJWNMoLlYkLgUiGox+WpLc/etvZeYu8BaGbvqSQIVlYW4jLxHbgzGb2dIMS59c7ZfH9VcJZwnYRwWoWJWpfWmj5Ii9l7MEeu8rg46l1Qy+U7g3Od9+hWi9aN2X6nhK0G8YrELOliAqOh4L1/+g9+596PfepjNx0XkfLV/9nu0u5FAXPpn5UT//SF5i2/VZQv/8cdaSLicSQOBkPrIBokWKv4iNOoKpL5WFELOEHF+gmaHTUnDWTCICGYihVPnMUZ8fUAIRaUNfbaIdb9ow1Tj7+r3imswNMFyxWIAG2FNBGkkqjKsZ7BEDXKVoi2HSCgW405unVDirIySMmzwHCQP/gbn7nn5/bwb8cPHTpUQ5w+fAnpUt2sfx/T02/96w9y+n8f2jvYyNJ8wSDiJKVohI3NEgYJqg6XKpqkaO6mX08w0ChV8NkkKuh7/hP7Pqnd87Gq1rpybH+6qCk6Lz+agu46EpNNXR0CZcz2ddFA7FXUObKcibX9dYCyterfAEu5Z+gVDTVXHbj6c5+975q/uv/++9eeffbZQAw04xP1Q7/Xlul6jXQpBEBmNjfZD394P2/6sQcWy9UPDEc5LstsdOc5ZRM4XVS4LLH2ch1KqBKXnHWGBySYyUjSSXUuxLRr3+aLm8C03Xv9153wTBzLnq9gXUFqy/olKaEqDcVrxSp4WmfoXghYV6hY719ZIcdCljFKFeqWhPF3Dx265tevSr/1rQceeOAMMTkc950QdPv+tmvM2e1rTxk+3Xxv77nlt386GRd/spT6JB8kVgaWZOCFzbphs7FGjC7zaKbWSoYoBD6O/EwmOKytHyiTkdt59J1W6PazGkOYrkNsP2D6v4emNhSxrgy86eDn2iaLiGCqPmCqvzbGD73HpwFCxSS0muIAAATiSURBVPJI/vbdb/7Pv3zkkUdOnzhxoiQiAb0t9PZ9rdBJ40UXhN0SgD7z5zE9oWN+t6U/sCJv/dk/HtTlh5byHAE0H4AImjiKoIzrFpUEzQWVYFoh98aMDHAupnbZNqq3je6eAPTpVcARTHP7zhtMK24K+CiWh6g65pvdT11gqJ48T3BiGilJy6du3P/i7504/JWjhw8fHjNleMOrhaA7N08Y4CILwW4KQJ/xHfM7xs/uu+OEa37kZrf3PX86DLx5NMzsz08MuSN1VE4o60DhHZLEIoqBM/SPnu0W0Ng3CLU1fENTQxoTQOJtD6CKEHsdNrUlhbrPd3Y9kpaKNBpVfzxZBIbSkEtC5iU6pkDenjiQHf+z6tkvf/3IkSObGHMbjJnd8Szj+/vAdu3Q9xMuCu2GAPRtfX+Uz2P+TgKRcNM9t4tc+yuL6eCawcIi4hLT8Cmo95AmlAJFY+1YZRiXc0k1NnSI/5NzOBSSzBjqYhp5MmVrmsHT0CKhjY2qt2uPDsiR4My5awK5VwY4shCQBlzAchWuXl0anvhHf/zhh48cOXKG7cw+236n9/pCcFF9gt0SgP7o35nJ2wWhLxDT89f/xG3CwXtHw5VbB4sjW5tIICTORvMowaXWs7eSmjo4qrq2vALbVXs3kjuwp2P+dIXw+Aucs0pk55DSnDvvBR8SMm1JgVQ91JXVDKqgWuLT6sggOf5wc+yRJ55//vn+iJ9lcP/1+QrHrmiB730B6I6X3nIVb7r9E/noujtGyWgh1RgWpiB5jmYNZEPrTu49tTYEtVU9Ghdih+347zftlMlMa0S861bugKQVHC2p9zg8vjUb7xpBi9Ja5bYgWmzl7pV/dVvf/tLaC08dX1tbKzj3CL/sBeD1m4CdP+s5ePstsvem9w+G170398MDaeotieRzNDNG46Hr9U8yLQZBA8T6D+ck9hwIUGOpY284wVTVt1bdu1kjpU0PoxqfSuX0d3T8zJPVya8/vbq6WvBqBp9LrV+2JqC77oU5gef+3PZt/01Xc+C292WLV92Y5HvflvvR/mSUmWqPDR9VY6UvWHl3F0Z2U/XrQLemn2jX87BGimCTNcriVNquH22Kl59rTz/1ZLF+9MUzZ87MC+PmbTs5d5etE9i/7vmHgTszOWG7AM1qFr/t+qN9i3z/rTf6lRtuSFy+lA33HfSkI6+NC37xJh/cJO1sNt/ZWsXtxtGqBYpqLHr6eFMVm7L10nPlS0/9Tzte3SiKomNIPzzr72dHap+B88K9yzoM7F/73EDQzgydZfi849lrujn37COQ3XPN++3a2/cRuVlQZlYQ5gnD7PEsY+dtlw0QNHuP+VBwtNTMZ+o85p6N4Wdj/uzWf7aOdOZ4dttJCM5HIM6lOS5LKHin+7jeuXna4UK32evNY/z5ZtvmCcA8rXA2YXgtW/96cJklg852z74wzGqIeQKy07l539vp+vOeo6OdtABMmdIfnbPHOwnHvM/udP3Z59hVeiMEYKf7z9rn/us+Q2eFZfb82b4/e595NKtyw8z5eX5C97lZTXE+3+/f95LTGy0AfZp9lllnbR5zZ8/NO563Px/Ss+zPdjx7bt5+9h5vGH0vCcAszXu2eYycd3wuxp9LA8x7fTZmzjuex9w3nOFX6ApdoSt0ha7QFbpCV+gK8f+ipUkRZil1JgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />

</p>
```

As you can see it retrive the **${DATA}** parameter from the velocity context object and it works fine.

The problem is that at the end I am trying to insert a **png** image coded in **base64**.

The problem is that, when I receive the e-mail, it is shown the **alt** attribute content (so it is shown the **info** string) but not the image.

It seems to me very strange because if I insert the previous **img** tag into an empty html page the image is correctly displayd.

Why into my received e-mail the **src** attribute is not defined and the image is not shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently faced a similar problem and found out, that some email clients do not support embedded images. [Here you can see a list of mail clients and their support for embedded emails.](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/)  So maybe your problem has nothing to do with Velocity but rather then with your email client. [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email)