# Mustachejs adding images

Tags: node.js, mustache

I currently have some templating for my emails using mustachejs. I am using node.js where the templates gets generated.

But I want to add images to this on the server side however when I create an img src tag within the template it doesn't show the image within the generated email.

The path is correct. Is there a different way this has to be done?

Comment: You have to use an url to show the image as sending it as an attachment neither local path will work.

If that still doesn't works, a sample of the code you're using would help to see what's wrong.

Comment: As an alternative way, you can loop trough your images before rendering the template and convert them in base64, using the CID method as suggested here [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/36870709 )