# how to send mail with image data and convert to image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using niceeditor like ckeditor and m upload image as a drag and drop but that image when i send email that time not go through email.Can any one help me.my code is bellow

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('email', "Day Lewis – conference");
$this->email->reply_to('daylewis@principalge.com', $this->system->site_name);
$this->email->to($guest_email['guest_email']);
$this->email->subject($selectedemaildata[0]['emailheader']);
$this->email->message($selectedemaildata[0]['email']);   **// contain image data**
$this->email->send();
```

[image: that type of data stored in database table]

Comment: Can you explain what "not go through email" means in more detail? (Generally we need answers to: What did you do? What did you expect? What did you get?) If you mean embedding images in base64 then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: I have nice editor and m drag and drop image in nice editor that image data stored in database and some content which i wrote in editor all data are stored in table but when i fatch and use for email message that time only content send but image is not gone through mail.

Comment: You may not be doing anything wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email  Embedding base 64 images is always going to be open to being distrusted and not displayed by the interpreting software. Sorry I cannot be any more help. What you have output looks like it is good.