# CS-cart 4.5.2 images in email templates

Tags: php, email, cs-cart

I am trying to add images to an email template in cs-cart 4.5.2..

in the template:

```
<img src="http://the-domain.com/design/themes/responsive/media/images/facebook.png">
```

in the email I recieve:

```
<img src="cid:csimg1.png">
```

The image url changes to "cid:csimg1.png", and the image is not found in the email.

Is there a specific way to add images for email templates in cs cart 4.5.2 ?

PS: The url of my image works correctly when I paste it into my browser.

Thank you for your help,
Jordan

Comment: Images are commonly stripped out of email messages as they are commonly used for tracking purposes primarily by spammers. You have no control over this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email

Answer (score 0):

Try the image tag with base64 encoded data as follows:-

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64-ENCODED-DATA-HERE">
```

like:-

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9i...">
```

to encode image to base64 encode you can use the following service:-

http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64