# (C#) Image in Mail not displayed in Outlook

Tags: c#, html, image, outlook, mailmessage

I want to send mails with images in them. The code I've written works fine, but for some reason unknown to me it wont work with Outlook clients.
The test mail I sent was (left: Thunderbird, right: Outlook):

[image: Mail as seen in a Thunderbird client]
[image: Mail as seen in an Outlook client]

What my code is supposed to do is: It takes the RTF from a `RichTextBox` and converts it to HTML. This leaves the images embedded in the HTML as base64 strings. I extract all base64 encoded images one by one and put them into a `MemoryStream` which is accepted by `LinkedResource`. Since mail clients usually don't accept embedded images I replace the embedded image in the HTML with a content-id. Then I set some properties of `LinkedResource` and add it to an `AlternateView`. This alternate view is then added to a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` and the mail is sent.
The corresponding code:

```cs
MemoryStream mem = null;
private readonly Regex embeddedImageRegex = new Regex("src=\"data:image/.*?\"");

public MyHTMLMailMessage() 
    : base()
{
    this.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    this.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    this.IsBodyHtml = true;
}

public bool Send()
{
    // create HTML View with images
    AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(HTML, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    ReplaceEmbeddedImagesWithCID(htmlView);
    this.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

    this.Body = HTML;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server, port);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = String.IsNullOrEmpty(username);

    try
    {
        client.Send(this);
        return true;
    }
    catch (SmtpException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        mem?.Close();
    }
}

private void ReplaceEmbeddedImagesWithCID(AlternateView altView)
{
    string extension;
    int imageIndex = 0;
    string contentID = $"image{imageIndex}";

    // go through every base64 string, create a content id and LinkedResource for it
    while (embeddedImageRegex.IsMatch(HTML))
    {
        extension = new Regex("image/.*?;").Match(HTML).Value
                    .Replace("image/", "")
                    .Replace(";", "");

        string base64img = embeddedImageRegex.Match(HTML).Value
                            .Replace("src=\"", "")
                            .Replace("\"", "")
                            .Split(',')[1];
        HTML = embeddedImageRegex.Replace(HTML, $"src=\"cid:image{imageIndex}\"", 1);

        byte[] byBitmap = Convert.FromBase64String(base64img);
        mem = new MemoryStream(byBitmap);
        mem.Position = 0;
        
        LinkedResource linkedImage = new LinkedResource(mem, $"image/{extension}");
        linkedImage.ContentId = contentID;

        altView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedImage);
        altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(HTML, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        imageIndex++;
    }
}
```

So I went through different solutions but none of them worked.
My steps so far:

1. I edited some registration keys in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Options\Mail` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common`
2. I left the image as base64 string in the HTML
3. There were some properties added

```cs
linkedImage.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
linkedImage.ContentType.Name = contentID;
linkedImage.ContentLink = new Uri($"cid:{contentID}");
this.Headers.Add("Content-ID", $"<image{imageIndex}>");
this.Headers.Add("X-Attachment-Id", $"image{imageIndex}");
altView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
```

None of this worked for me even although it seemed to help others. Did i overlook something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 images are blocked by default in Outlook.

You need to attach images to the email and set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the email (the DASL name is  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"). See [Embed Images in New Messages using a Macro](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/embed-images-messages-macro/) for more information.

Comment: That's the missing piece of information I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed it is not an image block from Trust Center Settings.

**Unblock image downloads for a single message:**
Click the InfoBar at the top of the message.
Click Download Pictures.

**Unblock image downloads for all messages:**
Outlook 2007
On the "Tools" menu, click Trust Center > Automatic Download.
Uncheck the "Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items" check box.

**Outlook 2010 and Up:**
On the "File" tab, click Options > Trust Center.
Under Microsoft Outlook Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings.
Uncheck the "Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items" check box.

**Unblock picture downloads for all messages from a particular email address or domain:**
In an open message that was sent from a particular email address or domain, right-click on a blocked item.
Do one of the following:

- Click Add Sender to Safe Senders List.
- Click Add the Domain [@domain] to Safe Senders List.

Comment: The image is indeed blocked by the trust center, but only its download. After I downloaded the image manually (or disabled the blocking of images) I get the empty image as seen in my question.

Comment: Oh I get. Would you opt for the usual linking of images from a server online?

Comment: The images cannot be stored on a server before sending the mail. I could use absolute paths though. I don't know if that would have the same effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email