# XSL to Outlook: Picture is red X

Tags: html, xml, xslt, .net-4.0

Background:

I am sending HTML emails from Oracle using XSLT.

1. XML is transformed using XSL and sent to stored procedure from .NET 4.  The XSL processor is System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.
2. My custom Oracle Stored Procedure SEND_MAIL_HTML calls UTL_SMTP
3. Outlook receives e-mail and the picture is Red X. **<-- problem**
4. Using View Source, copy all the content into a file and save.
5. Double-click on the file and the picture shows up fine.

The img tag in my HTML has a src="data:image/jpeg;base64, *LotsOfAlphanumerics*" element.

Please ask me how to clarify the problem and I will.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send a base64 image in HTML email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email)

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049453/how-to-successfully-embed-images-in-html-for-display-in-webmail-clients

Comment: What does "the picture is Red X" mean?

Comment: I can't help shouting out to this URL for something very helpful ... http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/html-with-embedded-images-from-plsql.php

Comment: And this one helps too ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried hard to make the cid method work, per the URL's below, but I ended up spending too much time on it.

In the end, I ended up posting the image to a public URL.

*See also:*

- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/html-with-embedded-images-from-plsql.php
- [embedding image in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email)
- [Send a base64 image in HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242489/send-a-base64-image-in-html-email)