# Best practices for including images in HTML Email?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have been tasked with changing some email templates (password resets, etc.). The new templates I have been given are simple, but include a few small images for aesthetic reasons. What are the best practices for including these in emails?

As I understand it, many email providers block images by default due to privacy and tracking concerns (tagging users using unique image URLs for each recipient and waiting for their browser to load the resource). Would using a data URI for images be an effective solution to this issue, or are these blocked too? (And if so, I would love to know why!)

Aside from the fact that really old browsers (IE7-) do not support this format, are there any other reasons not to use it? As far as I understand it, when it comes to email you need to be as simple and transparent as possible, and I worry that doing something a little bit unusual like this could set off alarm bells in the spam filters. Is this concern justified?

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580355/can-you-send-images-in-datauri-format-to-gmail gmail blocks data uris - so that idea may be a non starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Foreground Images (JPG, PNG, GIF) are universally understood in all major email clients**. Markup is the same as on a web page (`<img src="">`). Things like background images, SVG, or data URIs work in *some* clients but not all, it's best not to rely on these as a way to display essential images. [SVG support in email clients](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/).

Some email clients block images by default, but can be downloaded is user clicks a button. [Here is a good rundown on image blocking in email clients](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-email-image-blocking).