# How to embed an image in email?

Tags: java, spring, email, gmail

I am trying to write a Java program where I need to send an image to Gmail. I am sending the image as an embedded object.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACcAAAAsCAYAAADmZKH2AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABISURBVFhH7c4hAQAgEAAxEhGGZN8YOkwhTsxvnT33V+VUOVVOlVPlVDlVTpVT5VQ5VU6VU+VUOVVOlVPlVDlVTpVT5dTHubkPuMrNUFKjQWUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
```

Other mail service providers are showing it fine, but Gmail specifically is removing it, so it is not visible in the message.

How can I make it visible in Gmail as well as the other mail service providers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580355/can-you-send-images-in-datauri-format-to-gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Place the image in a publicly accessible server and give the url for src attribute instead of dataUrl.

Comment: I want to add the image as object rather than sending as URL

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Gmail, outlook etc. They ignore base64 images.
For further information follow the link at below.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/

There is an alternative way for doing this. Embed images in the email using the `cid` method. (Basically including the image as an attachment, and then embedding it).

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/how-to/2008/08/embedding-images-revisited/

Comment: As per the comment, it is written as "Gmail - No-Image will not display"